# Let $R$ be a ring. Let $A=(\alpha_{ij}), B=(\beta_{kl})\in M_{n\times m}(R)$. What is $A\boxtimes B=(\alpha_{rs}\beta_{rs})?$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, terminology

*This is a little difficult to search for, so please excuse me if it has been asked before.*

### The Question:

Let $R$ be a ring. Consider the matrices $A=(\alpha_{ij}), B=(\beta_{kl})\in M_{n\times m}(R)$. What is the name of the operation $\boxtimes$ given by $$A\boxtimes B=(\alpha_{rs}\beta_{rs})?$$

### An Example:

If $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2\\ 
3 & 4\\
5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
2 & 3\\
4 & 5
\end{pmatrix},$ then

$$A\boxtimes B=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2\\
6 & 12\\
20 & 30
\end{pmatrix}.$$

### An Observation:

Since each $A\boxtimes B\in M_{n\times m}(R)$ is $n\times m$ multiplications in $R$, much like $A+ B\in M_{n\times m}(R)$ is $n\times m$ additions in $R$, we have that $(M_{n\times m}(R), +, \boxtimes)\cong R^{n\times m}$ is a ring.

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) or the *entrywise* or *elementwise* product.